# Best regression model, given coefficient of variation $R^2$ and mean-squared error

Tags: regression, self-study, anova, multiple-regression

If you have 3 separate models in a multiple regression problem (and 3 ANOVA tables), which would be best given that you have the coefficient of determination, $R^2$, and mean-squared error values?

So you have 1 table, with just $X_1$, another with just $X_2$ and a third with $X_1$, $X_2$ combined. Which is best given specific $R^2$ values and MSE values?

I assume you're looking for the highest $R^2$ values, but how does MSE play into this?

Comment: From your comment to @Learnerbeaver's reply below, I gather that this is homework/self study, which is why I added the relevant tag. So a few hints: what have you learned about the effect on R^2 when adding a variable to a model? How do R^2 and MSE relate? What does this imply about how useful R^2 and MSE are in selecting models (and why Learnerbeaver recommends adjusted R^2)? Finally, look at your specific values of R^2 and MSE for the three models in the comment below. You may be able to figure out the answer yourself by now.

Comment: If you've studied AIC and BIC and so on in class, that might be what is being looked for.

Comment: Yes, it appears option 2 with X2 is the option, as MSE goes up when X1 is added to the model in the third option (X1,X2), so X2 would have to be it. Can you perhaps offer me a theoretical comment on why this is so?

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are also looking at adjusted r square.

A high r square and low mape could indicate over fitting.

The p values of the regressor and its sign in the two models could be compared.

aic can be compared. lower the better. 
hope it helps.

Comment: Adjusted R^2 is not to be used for this problem. From the values I calculated, I have: for X1: R2 = 8%, MSE=5900; for X2: R2 = 80.1%, MSE = 1880, for X1X2: R2=80.6%, MSE=1940. Which model do you feel is best? It appears to me as if it's a clear race between X2 and X1X2(combined), but which?

Comment: I would not take a stance between the two options, till I understand the problem and look at the interpretation offered by the two models. May be a model with x1, x2 and x1x2 will give you some insights. You can then possibly articulate interaction effects better. And, how are your residuals? Are you sure you have no information left there? Finally, why not adj r sq?

Comment: Let me try expressing my discomfort in a different way. If you only have 2 variables as regressors, you really don't need to do regression. You could just define business rules? Its kind of odd to use regression if you have only 1 or 2 variables in the model.